# Nexus 7 (2013) How do I disable Android OS updates?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-7

I want to disable OS updates on my rooted Nexus 7 (2013). Is there a way to stop the tablet from checking for these updates before I create the ROM rather than installing Disable Services or having to uncheck "show notifications" as I've seen in other posts?

Comment: Some ROMs have a dedicated system app that does the job of searching for a system update and alert the user. In Settings -> Apps -> All apps, do you see any app with the name (anywhere) 'System' or 'update'?

Comment: There is ConfigUpdater and Android System in All Apps. But just to clarify I'm creating my own ROM to flash and I want to be able to disable it from checking for the updates as part of the ROM that I am building.

Comment: Read this: http://androidforums.com/threads/nexus-7-how-to-disable-android-updates.896021/

Comment: After reading that it shows that I can check the notification box to prevent the notification box from appearing or disable "SystemUpdateService" using different apps.

So if the apps are able to accomplish what I want, there must be a way for me to accomplish this as part of the ROM that I am building.

When the app disables SystemUpdateService what is it actually modifying? Can I make the same changes as the app myself by finding and editing these files manually?